# Starting an Application via Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I can open Notepad just by typing notepad or notepad.exe in command prompt. But for other installed applications, I have to browse to the location first and then run the .exe file. Why is that? Can somebody explain this?

Comment: To the dupe closers - neither of the dupes answers the "Why is that? Can somebody explain this?" parts of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I have to browse to the location first and then run the .exe file.

This is because your other applications are not in the search path for exectable files.

Windows has a built in environment variable (`PATH`) which contains a list of directories. The list is searched when trying to find a command to execute:

> When a command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first look for an executable file in the current folder, if not found it will scan `%PATH%` to find it.

The current path can be displayed by typing `PATH` without any parameters on the command line.

For example here is my path:

```
F:\test>path
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\Calibre\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
;;C:\apps\NTP\bin
```

---

#### How do I add a program to the path?

**From a command line:**

You can use the `set` command to do this

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\myapplication
```

Note:

- `myapplication` is the directory containing your application
- `set` will only set the `PATH` for the current commmand prompt.
- Use `setx` to permanently change the `PATH`

**From the Windows GUI:**

> - Windows 8
>
>   1. From the Desktop, right-click the very bottom left corner of the screen to get the Power User Task Menu.
>   2. From the Power User Task Menu, click System.
>   3. Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
>   4. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab.
>   5. In the Environment Variables window (pictured below), highlight the Path variable in the "System variables" section and click the Edit
>        button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you want the
>        computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a
>        semicolon.
>
>   [image]
> - Windows 7
>
>   1. From the Desktop, right-click the Computer icon and select Properties. If you don't have a Computer icon on your desktop, click
>        the Start button, right-click the Computer option in the Start menu,
>        and select Properties.
>   2. Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
>   3. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab.
>   4. In the Environment Variables window (pictured below), highlight the Path variable in the "System variables" section and click the Edit
>        button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you want the
>        computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a
>        semicolon.
>
>   [image]

Source [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.
- [path](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) - Display or set a search path for executable files.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).

Comment: So if i temporarily create a path and close the command prompt my path will be resetted?

Comment: If you use `set` then yes, if you use `setx` then no. Please look at the further reading links I provided in my answer.

Comment: Note: Start\Run fetches data from fegistry SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications on top of paths from PATH (try "chrome", "acrord32" )